# Product url with category in magento search

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I want to set product url in search page with the product category. But it doesn't show category url.

> Example:-www.xxxxxx.com/maincategory/subcategory/product_name.html

But in search result, it shows
Example:-`www.xxxxxx.com/product_name.html`

I want to show url with a full category path like

> Example:-www.xxxxxx.com/maincategory/subcategory/product_name.html

How can I set this.

Comment: and what if the product is in 2 or more categories?

Comment: Yes, Product use in 1 or more categories.

Comment: I was asking you actually...what should happen if the product is in 2 categories and you search for it. What category name should be used in the url?

Comment: Only 1 Category need for url then what can I do?

Comment: If two categories selected, then it open www.xxxxxx.com/product_name.html that type link I need only for single category url.